# Why is MSAL on MAUI Windows not caching the account between application restarts?

Tags: maui, azure-ad-msal

Inside a MAUI .Net 8.0 app I have implemented MSAL. When run on Windows, the line `var accounts = await _pca!.GetAccountsAsync();` always returns 0 accounts after an application restart, even if I successfully authenticated before closing and restarting the app.

My expectation is that there would be 1 account returned by that line of code that I could then use to silently retrieve an Auth Token and use that Auth Token to access Microsoft services, and the same code when run on Android does exactly that.

What happens on Windows is that the MSAL login window is always launched after application restart, forcing me to choose the account I wish to use to authenticate with. Having successfully authenticated once, I am not required to enter my password and other authentication details in this helper window, I just have to choose the account and assuming it's the same one as I used before, then repeat authentication to the point of asking me password etc is not required.

As an additional point, and I don't know if this is related to the problem or not, the MSAL login window asking me to choose the account, is blank 99% of the time. When I hover over the area where the account is normally shown, the cursor turns into a hand indicating that there is a link there, I just click it and it selects that account in the same way as it would if I could see the account name - see screenshot below:

[image: Blank MSAL login window]

Here are the logs from the `IPublicClientApplication` object - this is from a second run of the application, having successfully authenticated during the first run of the app:

```
Information: False MSAL 4.59.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.1 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22631 [2024-02-29 12:24:19Z] [Internal cache] Total number of cache partitions found while getting refresh tokens: 0
Information: False MSAL 4.59.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.1 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22631 [2024-02-29 12:24:19Z - 5882229a-d1f6-4ebd-a4c4-fae34be2ebb8] [Region discovery] Not using a regional authority. 
Information: False MSAL 4.59.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.1 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22631 [2024-02-29 12:24:19Z] Found 0 cache accounts and 0 broker accounts
Information: False MSAL 4.59.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.1 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22631 [2024-02-29 12:24:19Z] Returning 0 accounts
Information: False MSAL 4.59.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.1 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22631 [2024-02-29 12:24:19Z - d2b38fd1-46b0-4ab2-8ba8-e6dd6864241b] MSAL MSAL.NetCore with assembly version '4.59.0.0'. CorrelationId(d2b38fd1-46b0-4ab2-8ba8-e6dd6864241b)
Information: False MSAL 4.59.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.1 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22631 [2024-02-29 12:24:19Z - d2b38fd1-46b0-4ab2-8ba8-e6dd6864241b] === InteractiveParameters Data ===
LoginHint provided: False
User provided: False
UseEmbeddedWebView: NotSpecified
ExtraScopesToConsent: 
Prompt: not_specified
HasCustomWebUi: False

Information: False MSAL 4.59.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.1 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22631 [2024-02-29 12:24:19Z - d2b38fd1-46b0-4ab2-8ba8-e6dd6864241b] 
=== Request Data ===
Authority Provided? - True
Scopes - https://outlook.office.com/POP.AccessAsUser.All
Extra Query Params Keys (space separated) - 
ApiId - AcquireTokenInteractive
IsConfidentialClient - False
SendX5C - False
LoginHint ? False
IsBrokerConfigured - False
HomeAccountId - False
CorrelationId - d2b38fd1-46b0-4ab2-8ba8-e6dd6864241b
UserAssertion set: False
LongRunningOboCacheKey set: False
Region configured: 

Information: False MSAL 4.59.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.1 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22631 [2024-02-29 12:24:19Z - d2b38fd1-46b0-4ab2-8ba8-e6dd6864241b] === Token Acquisition (InteractiveRequest) started:
     Scopes: https://outlook.office.com/POP.AccessAsUser.All
    Authority Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Information: False MSAL 4.59.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.1 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22631 [2024-02-29 12:24:19Z - d2b38fd1-46b0-4ab2-8ba8-e6dd6864241b] [Instance Discovery] Instance discovery is enabled and will be performed
Information: False MSAL 4.59.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.1 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22631 [2024-02-29 12:24:19Z - d2b38fd1-46b0-4ab2-8ba8-e6dd6864241b] [Region discovery] Not using a regional authority. 
Information: False MSAL 4.59.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.1 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22631 [2024-02-29 12:24:19Z - d2b38fd1-46b0-4ab2-8ba8-e6dd6864241b] Fetching instance discovery from the network from host login.microsoftonline.com. 
Information: False MSAL 4.59.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.1 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22631 [2024-02-29 12:24:20Z - d2b38fd1-46b0-4ab2-8ba8-e6dd6864241b] Authority validation enabled? True. 
Information: False MSAL 4.59.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.1 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22631 [2024-02-29 12:24:20Z - d2b38fd1-46b0-4ab2-8ba8-e6dd6864241b] Authority validation - is known env? True. 
Information: False MSAL 4.59.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.1 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22631 [2024-02-29 12:24:20Z - d2b38fd1-46b0-4ab2-8ba8-e6dd6864241b] Using WebView1 embedded browser because the authority is Aad. WebView2 does not provide SSO.
Information: False MSAL 4.59.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.1 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22631 [2024-02-29 12:24:25Z - d2b38fd1-46b0-4ab2-8ba8-e6dd6864241b] [Legacy WebView] Redirect URI was reached. Stopping WebView navigation...
Information: False MSAL 4.59.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.1 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22631 [2024-02-29 12:24:25Z - d2b38fd1-46b0-4ab2-8ba8-e6dd6864241b] An authorization code was retrieved from the /authorize endpoint. 
Information: False MSAL 4.59.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.1 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22631 [2024-02-29 12:24:25Z - d2b38fd1-46b0-4ab2-8ba8-e6dd6864241b] Exchanging the auth code for tokens. 
Information: False MSAL 4.59.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.1 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22631 [2024-02-29 12:24:25Z - d2b38fd1-46b0-4ab2-8ba8-e6dd6864241b] === InteractiveParameters Data ===
LoginHint provided: False
User provided: False
UseEmbeddedWebView: NotSpecified
ExtraScopesToConsent: 
Prompt: not_specified
HasCustomWebUi: False

Information: False MSAL 4.59.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.1 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22631 [2024-02-29 12:24:25Z - d2b38fd1-46b0-4ab2-8ba8-e6dd6864241b] Checking client info returned from the server..
Information: False MSAL 4.59.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.1 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22631 [2024-02-29 12:24:25Z - d2b38fd1-46b0-4ab2-8ba8-e6dd6864241b] Saving token response to cache..
Information: False MSAL 4.59.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.1 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22631 [2024-02-29 12:24:25Z - d2b38fd1-46b0-4ab2-8ba8-e6dd6864241b] [Region discovery] Not using a regional authority. 
Information: False MSAL 4.59.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.1 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22631 [2024-02-29 12:24:25Z - d2b38fd1-46b0-4ab2-8ba8-e6dd6864241b] [SaveTokenResponseAsync] Saving AT in cache and removing overlapping ATs...
Information: False MSAL 4.59.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.1 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22631 [2024-02-29 12:24:25Z - d2b38fd1-46b0-4ab2-8ba8-e6dd6864241b] Looking for scopes for the authority in the cache which intersect with https://outlook.office.com/POP.AccessAsUser.All
Information: False MSAL 4.59.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.1 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22631 [2024-02-29 12:24:25Z] [Internal cache] Total number of cache partitions found while getting access tokens: 0
Information: False MSAL 4.59.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.1 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22631 [2024-02-29 12:24:25Z - d2b38fd1-46b0-4ab2-8ba8-e6dd6864241b] Intersecting scope entries count - 0
Information: False MSAL 4.59.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.1 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22631 [2024-02-29 12:24:25Z - d2b38fd1-46b0-4ab2-8ba8-e6dd6864241b] Matching entries after filtering by user - 0
Information: False MSAL 4.59.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.1 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22631 [2024-02-29 12:24:25Z - d2b38fd1-46b0-4ab2-8ba8-e6dd6864241b] [SaveTokenResponseAsync] Saving Id Token and Account in cache ...
Information: False MSAL 4.59.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.1 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22631 [2024-02-29 12:24:25Z - d2b38fd1-46b0-4ab2-8ba8-e6dd6864241b] [SaveTokenResponseAsync] Saving RT in cache...
'MSALTestApp.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\8.0.1\System.Collections.Immutable.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Information: False MSAL 4.59.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.1 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22631 [2024-02-29 12:24:25Z - d2b38fd1-46b0-4ab2-8ba8-e6dd6864241b] 
    === Token Acquisition finished successfully:
Information: False MSAL 4.59.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.1 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22631 [2024-02-29 12:24:25Z - d2b38fd1-46b0-4ab2-8ba8-e6dd6864241b]  AT expiration time: 29/02/2024 13:48:08 +00:00, scopes: https://outlook.office.com/POP.AccessAsUser.All. source: IdentityProvider
Information: False MSAL 4.59.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.1 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22631 [2024-02-29 12:24:25Z - d2b38fd1-46b0-4ab2-8ba8-e6dd6864241b] Fetched access token from host login.microsoftonline.com. 
Information: False MSAL 4.59.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.1 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22631 [2024-02-29 12:24:25Z - d2b38fd1-46b0-4ab2-8ba8-e6dd6864241b] 
[LogMetricsFromAuthResult] Cache Refresh Reason: NotApplicable
[LogMetricsFromAuthResult] DurationInCacheInMs: 0
[LogMetricsFromAuthResult] DurationTotalInMs: 5814
[LogMetricsFromAuthResult] DurationInHttpInMs: 720

Information: False MSAL 4.59.0.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 8.0.1 Microsoft Windows 10.0.22631 [2024-02-29 12:24:25Z - d2b38fd1-46b0-4ab2-8ba8-e6dd6864241b] TokenEndpoint: ****
```

I have setup a repo containing the code to replicate this problem: https://github.com/benempson/msal-test

The `IPublicClientApplication` object is configured in the various `PlatformSetup.cs` partial classes inside the Platforms folder, `Setup()` method, which in turn is called from `MauiProgram.cs`. The actual authentication calls are made in the `Home.razor` file.

What am I doing wrong here? All the MSAL code is taken from Microsoft examples.

EDIT: Just to add setup code so it is visible here:
PlatformSetup.cs (_serviceCollection is the DI container):

```
string? clientId = SecureStorage.GetAsync("ClientId").Result;
PublicClientApplicationBuilder pcab = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, "common")
    .WithRedirectUri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient")
    .WithLogging((level, message, pii) =>
    {
        _logger.LogInformation(message);
    }, Microsoft.Identity.Client.LogLevel.Info, enablePiiLogging: false, enableDefaultPlatformLogging: true);

_serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IPublicClientApplication>(pcab.Build());
```

Home.razor:

```
@page "/"
@inject Microsoft.Identity.Client.IPublicClientApplication _pca
@using System.Text.Json

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

@_log


@code {
    private MarkupString _log;

    private string[] _scopes = new[] {
        "https://outlook.office.com/POP.AccessAsUser.All",
    };

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
        AuthenticationResult authResult;
        var accounts = await _pca!.GetAccountsAsync();
        log.AppendLine($"Found {accounts.Count()} cached accounts");
        bool needsInteractiveLogin = accounts.Count() < 1;
        if (!needsInteractiveLogin)
        {
            try
            {
                authResult = await _pca!
                    .AcquireTokenSilent(_scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                    .ExecuteAsync();
            }
            catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
            {
                needsInteractiveLogin = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.AppendLine($"MSAL silent error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

        if (needsInteractiveLogin)
        {
            log.AppendLine("Doing interactive login");
            try
            {
                authResult = await _pca!
                    .AcquireTokenInteractive(_scopes)
                    .ExecuteAsync();

                log.AppendLine($"authResult = {(authResult == null ? "null" : $"Authenticated: {authResult.Account.HomeAccountId}")}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.AppendLine($"MSAL interactive error: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
        else
            log.AppendLine("No interactive login required");

        _log = new MarkupString(log.ToString().ReplaceLineEndings($"<br />{Environment.NewLine}"));
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```